# Submitting an array of values through ajax to external php script (datatables deferred rendering)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a form on one of my pages that contains check boxes linked with the primary id of some information that gets recalled on another page based on whether the check box was checked our not. I recently switched to using jquery-datatables on this table with deferred rendering, so now it appears that my form (created with php/html) can only see some 150 elements that are in the viewport and only sends those even when all the checkboxes have been selected. My question is: how can I alternatively collect these checkbox ids from the entire table and send them through ajax when my 'compareRowButton' is clicked?

Here is what my form looks like now:

```
<form action='comparables/compare_baddebt.php' method='post' name='compareForm'>
<button type='submit' style='margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:10px;' class='btn btn-default compareRowButton'>Compare Selected Rows</button>

//lets just pretend that the only thing here is the checkbox
<input type='checkbox' id='1' value='1' class='compareCheck' name='post_id[]'/> // checkbox storing id into post_id
<input type='checkbox' id='2' value='2' class='compareCheck' name='post_id[]'/>
</form>
```

I'm not exactly a jquery wizard so forgive me, but this is the script I've put in place to select/deselect all the checkboxes:

```
$('#selectall').on('click', function() {  //on click 
    var cells = dTable.cells( ).nodes();
    $( cells ).find(':checkbox').prop('checked',this.checked);         
    });
```

The reason I post this is because I'm assuming that one of these methods can be tweaked to get back the value of the checkboxes including the hidden rows from deferred rendering (.cells().nodes() are apart of datatables api).

**What I need to know is how can I store those ID's in an array within jquery and then post them to compare_baddebt.php (action of the form) using jquery/ajax as opposed to a straight submission of the form through html.**

I know how to send a single variables through an ajax post but collecting an array and sending it in the right format for recall eludes me.

Currently my compare_baddebt.php accepts the `post_id` array like so :

```
$in = $_POST['post_id'];
```

and then cycles through the array with a foreach to recall the individual rows and put them in a new table for comparisons.

```
foreach ($in as $id){
    $query = $link->prepare("SELECT id,provider_num, provider_name, 261_total_bad_debts, 271_medicare_bad_debts, 281_non_medicare_bad_debts, 1_cost_to_charge_ratio, 291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts
                            FROM `s10`
                            WHERE `id` = :id");
    $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Thanks in advance, if you need any more info I'd be glad to provide

Comment: the answer is already tagged in your question, try to create an XMLHttpRequest thru `$.ajax` since you're already using jQuery

Comment: @Ghost what do you mean the answer was tagged in my question? I know I have to use ajax, my main question is what is the format for saving a php array into a javascript variable. 

`var ele_id = $(this).attr('id');
   console.log(ele_id);
   console.log('clicked');
       $.ajax({
          type : 'post',
           url : 'query/modalquery_providerlist.php', // in here you should put your query 
          data :  'post_id='+ ele_id` how does one do this with an array instead

Answer (score 0):

With deferred rendering not all table rows will be available immediately, therefore you won't be able to query or set state of all check boxes.

In order to be able to send a list of items checked, you need to add `click` event handler for each check box and store their state in global variable as key/value pair. Upon form submission you need to convert this object into array containing checked items only.

Below is just an example illustrating the logic above, please modify according to your needs.

**JavaScript:**

```
// Global variable holding current state of the check boxes
var g_compare_posts = {};

// Handle click on compare check box
$('table.dataTable').on('click', '.compareCheck', function (e){
    g_compare_posts[this.value] = this.checked;
});

// Handle click on 'Submit' button
$('.compareRowButton').on('click', function(e){
   // Produce a list of checked items
   var compare_posts_checked = [];
   for (var post_id in g_compare_posts) {
      if (g_compare_posts.hasOwnProperty(post_id) && g_compare_posts[post_id]) {
         compare_posts_checked.push(post_id);
      }
   }

   // Send AJAX request
   $.ajax(document.compareForm.action, {
      'data': {'post_id' : compare_posts_checked }
   });

   e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you want to have the ability to select all checkboxes, you need to send the state of that checkbox to the server-side PHP script and adjust your SQL query accordingly, i.e. do not apply `WHERE` condition or apply the same condition you used to produce the initial table.